# Concatenating first-order high-pass filters

Tags: operational-amplifier, high-pass-filter

I have the following circuit, which is an active high-pass filter with the knee frequency \$ f_{-3 dB} = \frac{1}{2\pi RC} = \text{1 kHz}\$

[image]

I wanted to concatenate two of those systems in order to make a second-order HPF:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Htg7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I did, I noticed that the knee frequency shifted to \$ f_{-3 dB} = \text {~1.4 kHz}\$

I have tried to look up the mathematics behind why that is, but I couldn't find anything on the subject.

I'd like to know the relationship behind the shift on the knee frequency to concatenation of systems like that.

Note: I don't want to build a second order HPF with one op-amp because in my circuit one of the legs of the op-amp is connected to ground, and the input voltage is as well and I can't change that.

My reasoning was:
$$ HPF(s) = \frac{sRC}{sRC + 1} $$
therefore
$$ HPF(s)\cdot HPF(s) =\frac{s^2R^2C^2}{(sRC + 1)^2} = \frac{s^2}{s^2 + \frac{2s}{RC} + \frac{1}{R^2C^2}}  $$
So as I understood (which is wrong):
$$ \omega_0 = \frac{1}{RC} $$

**Edit:**
I ended up solving the equation $$ |HPF(s) \cdot HPF(s) | = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $$ with $$ \omega = 2\pi \cdot 1000 $$ and I found the C values that get a -3 dB frequency at 1000 Hz.

Comment: Logical. When you "concatenate" two same filters as you do, the new frequency corner is multiplied by sqrt(2) in this case of HPF. In the case of LPF filters, it would be divided by sqrt(2).

Comment: @Antonio51 Thank you! I made a mistake in thinking the transfer function is still in canonical form, I understand now what I should do.

Comment: Not asked, but concatenating 1st order RC filters is useless if you want steeper  transition slope between passband and stopband. Making a properly designed 2nd order filter would be more effective.

Comment: Sorry... the factor sqrt(2) I used is only, if I remember well, for the changed "rise times" ...

Comment: @EdwardJosef Do you have any remaining questions? Or do you have what you needed to see?

Comment: The circuit you have shown is not a filter at allRemove R2 and connect 1 end of R1 or C1 to the inverting input and 1 end of R1 to the ground and 1 end of C1 to the output of the opamp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cascaded 1st order filters, when buffered and with the same elements, converge towards a Gaussian bell. It only happens after many such stages, but that's the point of convergence.

For your case, as you have correctly shown, the transfer function is:

$$H(s)=\dfrac{s}{s+\dfrac{1}{RC}} \tag{1}$$

Cascading \$N\$ such stages means the overall transfer function will be of the form:

$$G(s)=H(s)^N \tag{2}$$

Since the denominator has the same form, for whatever power of \$N\$, the \$s^0\$ term will be of the form \$1/(RC)^N\$. For a 1st order, the attenuation @1 Hz is always -3 dB (\$1/\sqrt2=1/2^{1/2}\$). For two cascaded sections, the transfer function becomes a 2nd order, and solving for the frequency at a specific attenuation is better suited for squared terms (considering \$RC=1\$):

$$\begin{align}
G(j\omega)^2&=H(j\omega)^4\quad\Rightarrow \\
\dfrac{\omega^4}{\omega^4+2\omega^2+1}&=\dfrac12 \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

Solving the above will yield 4 roots since it's a 4th order, but two of them will be imaginary and one negative, which leaves the positive one as the real result:

$$\begin{cases}
\omega^{2\text{nd}}_{1,2}&=\pm\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}=\pm\sqrt{2^\frac02+2^\frac12} \\
\omega^{2\text{nd}}_{3,4}&=\pm\sqrt{1-\sqrt2} \tag{4} \\
\end{cases}$$

For a 3rd order the results are more complicated, as you would expect, but a pattern starts forming:

$$\omega^{3rd}_1=\sqrt{2^\frac03+2^\frac13+2^\frac23} \tag{5}$$

By now you can readily form a general formula that gives you the precise value for the frequency when the attenuation is -3 dB:

$$A_{-3\;\text{dB}}^{HP}=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}{2^\frac{k}{N}}} \tag{6}\label{6}$$

A simple numerical check with wxMaxima confirms it:

```
H(s) := s/(s + 1)$
n:7$
find_root( cabs( H(%i*w)^n )=1/2^-0.5, w, 1, 100 ); /* numerical */
float( sqrt( sum ( 2^(k/n), k, 0, n-1 ) ) ); /* analytical */
```

The results come up as:

```
3.099534753828498
3.099534753828497
```

the difference being in the last decimal, due to the numerical nature of `find_root()` (IIRC it uses Brent's method). And for `n=13`:

```
4.273111111613913
4.273111111613912
```

For the sake of completeness, cascaded 1st order lowpass will have this formula:

$$A_{-3\;\text{dB}}^{LP}=\sqrt{2^\frac1N-1} \tag{7}\label{7}$$

I'll leave it to you to prove it.

One thing to note is that everything above treats the *ideal* case, when buffers have infinite input impedance and zero output impedance, thus achieving perfect isolation. In practice this will not happen, so minor deviations will occur.

---

(edit)

Regarding \$\eqref{6}\$, it can be written in a different format, considering one thing: the corner frequency for the lowpass is gradually shifting downwards in frequency, and it does so relative to unity (or \$\omega_p\$, here 1). This means that the highpass will follow in the exact same manner, mirrored against \$\omega_p\$ in a geometrical sense: \$\omega_p^2=\omega_{_\text{LO}}\omega_{_\text{HI}}\$. This further means that the simpler, more digestible \$\eqref{7}\$ -- which can be derived a bit more easily (you did try it, didn't you?) -- can be used to obtain the same flavour formula for the highpass:

$$\begin{align}
{}&\begin{cases}
\omega_p^2&=\omega_{_\text{LO}}\omega_{_\text{HI}} \\
\omega_p&=1 \\
\omega_{_\text{LO}}&=\sqrt{2^\frac1N-1}
\end{cases} \\
\Rightarrow\quad 1^2&=\omega_{_\text{HI}}\sqrt{2^\frac1N-1} \\
\Rightarrow\quad \omega_{_\text{HI}}&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2^\frac1N-1}} \tag{8}\label{8}
\end{align}$$

Wolfram Alpha [confirms it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify+sum%282%5E%28k%2FN%29%2Ck%2C0%2CN-1%29).

Comment: I've added an alternative way of deriving \$\eqref{6}\$.

Answer (score 4):

> *I noticed that the knee frequency shifted to \$f_{−3dB}=\$ 1.4kHz*

**Fact 1**: when you buffer-cascade two 1st-order high-pass (or low-pass) filters you get a 2nd-order transfer function that **has** a Q-factor of exactly 0.5. This can be easily shown mathematically.

**Fact 2**: for any 2nd-order filter, the transfer function magnitude at \$\omega_0\$ (or \$\omega_n\$) **is** Q.

See the orange points in this 2nd-order low-pass image from [my basic website](http://stades.co.uk/): -

[image]

<sub>It's the same for a high pass but mirrored horizontally about the \$\omega_n\$ axis.</sub>

Hence, for a 2nd-order filter (using a buffer to isolate the two 1st-order stages), the transfer function magnitude (when \$\omega = \frac{1}{RC}\$), is 0.5 and, this is a magnitude of -6dB and not -3 dB.

This means you are not comparing apples with apples in terms of frequency and 3 dB points.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plot of function (blue) and cascading it 2 times.
Poles and zeroes do not change.
Only the measuring at -3 dB is the same.
So the "knee frequency" is higher, because the global function varies faster.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you realize now to you must increase RC by a factor of \$\sqrt(n)\$ for all n stages to have the same breakpoint as a 1st order filter and make all concurrent.

This will result in an underdamped pulse response with undershoot and longer group delay and worse for max data rates with ISI. The more stages you add, the worse it gets with more undershoot and higher Q.

Answer (score 0):

With the two first-order filters in series then you have a very droopy filter that is -6dB at the -3dB frequency of each filter. An active 2nd-order Butterworth Sallen and Key has a flat frequency response down to a sharp corner frequency then a fairly steep 12dB per octave slope using only a single opamp.
[image: SK highpass]