# Cut-off frequency for RC-filter with two resistors and two capacitors

Tags: filter, low-pass, bandwidth

I'm sort of hard stuck on this question regarding RC-filters. I've tried calculating the total resistance of the circuit but I felt that it was the wrong way. Than I tried calculating Vout in terms of Vin so that I could use the formula in the picture below to calculate the cut-off frequency, but I don't know how to get the right expression for Vout. I've tried using voltage division but I keep getting the wrong answer. The correct answer according to my book is around:

W = 0,64/(R*C)

[image: Formula used to find the expression for the cut-off frequency] = 1/sqrt(2)

[image: What the system looks like]

Comment: Please show your working so that someone can see where you went wrong.

Comment: [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/622198/95619) is very similar.

Comment: This may not help you in any way but I usually just simulate stuff like this. I am lazy that way.

Comment: If you look in the answer I linked you'll see that the formula agrees with that value that you seek but, that is only valid for *buffered* RC stages. What you have are two, *unbuffered* stages, so the transfer function changes. See [this answer](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286688/286690#answer-286690) (on Codidact) for the difference between the two. Which means that, if the book considers what you show in the picture as *unbuffered*, the bok is wrong. Can you show the whole part, or whole page? Or a link, maybe?

Answer (score 4):

### Getting the transfer function

You could just view it this way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx8M3A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Above, you can see that \$R\$ and \$Z_{_\text{C}}\$ form a voltage divider that divides \$V_{_\text{X}}\$ into \$V_{_\text{OUT}}\$. Also, \$R\$ and \$Z_{_\text{X}}\$ form a voltage divider that divides \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ into \$V_{_\text{X}}\$.

So:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{_\text{X}} &= V_{_\text{IN}}\left[\frac{1}{1+\frac{R}{Z_{_\text{X}}}}\right]\\\\
V_{_\text{OUT}} &= V_{_\text{X}}\left[\frac{1}{1+\frac{R}{Z_{_\text{C}}}}\right]\\\\
&\therefore\quad \frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{V_{_\text{IN}}}=\left[\frac{1}{1+\frac{R}{Z_{_\text{X}}}}\right]\cdot \left[\frac{1}{1+\frac{R}{Z_{_\text{C}}}}\right]
\end{align*}$$

Finding then that \$Z_{_\text{C}}=\frac1{s\,C}\$ and \$Z_{_\text{X}}=\frac{Z_{_\text{C}}}{1+\frac1{1+\frac{R}{Z_{_\text{C}}}}}\$, and setting \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{R\,C}\$, then the Laplace transfer function is:

$$\begin{align*}
H\left(s\right)&=\frac{\omega_{_0}^2}{s^2+3 \omega_{_0}\, s+\omega_{_0}^2}\\\\\text{or,}\\\\
H\left(s=j\omega\right)&=\frac1{\left(1-\left[\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right]^2\right)+j\,3\left[\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right]}
\end{align*}$$

### SymPy confirmation

Just to confirm, let's use SymPy:

```
zc = 1/s/c
zx = zc/(1+(1/(1+r/zc)))
tf2( 1 / (1+r/zx) / (1+r/zc) )
{omega: 1/(c*r), zeta: 3/2, P: [{A: 1, N: 0}]}
```

(The tf2 function is one I wrote. It's documented elsewhere in other answers I've provided here.)

This confirms \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{R\,C}\$ and since I should see a term in the denominator of \$2\zeta\,\omega_{_0}\,s\$ and I know that \$2\zeta=3\$ in this case, then it all appears in order to me. I didn't make an error in the algebra process I followed.

### Addressing the problem question

Your problem sets the *magnitude* to \$\lvert H\left(j\omega\right) \rvert=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\$. But that's \$\left(1-\left[\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right]^2\right)^2+\left(3\left[\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right]\right)^2 =\sqrt{2}^2=2\$.

So set a new parameter, \$x=\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\$ and solve for \$x\$:

$$\begin{align*}
\left(1-x^2\right)^2+\left(3x\right)^2 =2
\end{align*}$$

Note that you can now set \$y=x^2\$ and just solve for \$\left(1-y\right)^2+9 y =2\$ or \$y^2+7y-1=0\$, which easily works out to \$y=\frac{-7\pm\sqrt{49-4\cdot -1}}{2}=\frac{-7\pm\sqrt{53}}{2}\$. And since \$x=\sqrt{y}\$ you can select the real-valued version, which is \$x=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{53}-7}}{\sqrt{2}}\$. That's then the ratio of the two.

So \$\omega=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{53}-7}}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\omega_{_0}\approx \frac{0.37423}{R\,C}\$. And it disagrees, I think, with the answer you suggested you are supposed to get.

### LTspice confirmation

Let's target \$\omega_{_0}=1\:\text{kHz}\$. I'll use \$R=15.915\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$C=10\:\text{nF}\$. We would predict that the \$-3.01\:\text{dB}\$ frequency will then be \$374.23\:\text{Hz}\$.

Running LTspice, I get:

[image]

Which does meet with prediction.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is not hard to show that:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2\right)^2+\left(3\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}}\tag1$$

So, solving for:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tag2$$

Gives:

$$\omega=\frac{1}{\text{CR}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{53}-7}{2}}\tag3$$